# I envisage that it does not. Can the sentence exist?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

The sentence is my answer to the question of whether robots will replace teachers in the future. I am not a linguist or a native speaker, therefore I cannot tell the truth. Personally, I speculate that the sentence can exist only if 'it does not' denotes 'it is impossible'. However, I should have answered the question this way:

It's tough to envisage the future without teachers; despite AI benefits over a person, computers cannot replace teachers. Neither can robots.

As you can see, envisage can be used without the second verb. Instead, a noun can stand after 'envisage'. Also, I could have used a modal verb instead of 'it does not'. Today I was passing the oral part of the state English exam. In result, I have scored 19 out of 20. No one has taken the sentence into consideration. One point was missed due to mispronunciation. **Nevertheless, I wonder if I can say 'I envisage it does not', and a native speaker will understand me; if it sounds natural, and if it is correct.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I envisage that it does not. Can the sentence exist?

Not really. The tense is wrong.

In this context "to envisage" means "to conceive of sth as a possibility in the future", so you'd need a future tense, not a present tense.

**Examples**:

> Will a robot ever be able to replace a teacher? I envisage it will not.
>
> Will robots ever replace teachers? I envisage they will not.

But "I envisage it does not" sounds wrong.

Also, the tendency in English is to make the first of the two verbs negative (as opposed to the second), so even better would be:

> Will a robot ever be able to replace a teacher?
> No. I don't envisage that it will.

Comment: I'm curious, why the downvote? I'd like to know if I said anything incorrect or if I have done anything wrong (as I am new to the site).